# Regex, exclude number starting with certain character

Tags: java, regex

I want to find number with don't proceed with £ character. Say I have a string:

> "Gross Domestic Product in 2012 was £127 billion"

I want to return **2012** only.

I ve tried `[^$][0-9]*` but this only ignores `$` character. Tried to match the whole word which starts and ends with number `\b[0-9]*\b` but `\b` applies only to `[0-9a-zA-Z]`

Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option which works (as tested using http://gskinner.com/RegExr) is:

```
(?<![£0-9])[0-9]+
```

This uses negative lookbehind to exclude £. The additional exclusion of 0-9 is to prevent it finding "27" in the above in addition to the "2012".

Comment: this lookbehind seems to be handy thing to know. thnx

Comment: Handy, but a bit bulky. Extracting subexpression matches with `()` from full match is more handy than using lookbehind, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix your string with space and search for the regex `\s[0-9]+` wich would mean 'digital prefix of word, starting with digit' This will exclude all words starting with $, £ or everything else except digit.

Comment: ok, i got it. But following expression will match preceding space before number.

Comment: I often use subexpressions to extract informative part of matched string - `\s([0-9]+)`. Or, in this trivial case, you can easily trim this extra space.

Comment: `\s[0-9]+` looks elegant of course but received result needs more processing though. thnx

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tool where you can try those out. Here is a sample way to do what you asked
 http://regex101.com/r/iH9uS8

Comment: expression will match preceding space before number. But thanks for the tool

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 (?:^|\\s)(\\d+)(?:\\s|$)
```